# Find $f_{X_1|X_2 = 2}(x_1)$ and check if $X_1+X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, conditional-probability

> **Problem:** Let $\underline X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)$ be a random vector with p.d.f.
> $$\color{blue}{f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \begin{cases}2e^{-x_2-2x_3} & 0<x_1<1, x_2>0,x_3>0\\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}}$$
> (a) Are $X_1,X_2,X_3$ independent?
> (b) Are $X_1+X_2$ and $X_3$ independent?
> (c) Find marginal p.d.fs of $X_1,X_2,X_3$.
> (d) Find conditional p.d.f. of $X_1$ given $X_2 = 2$.

---

$\color{red}{(a)}$ $f$ can be factored into functions involving only $x_2$ and only $x_3$ (there is no $x_1$), is that enough to conclude that the three random variables are independent? Anyway, I will find the marginals in part (c); so I think the question asker doesn't want us to compute the marginals in (a).

$\color{red}{(b)}$ Will I have to find the p.d.f. associated with $X_1+X_2$ and $X_3$ in this case? For $X_3$, let's say the marginal p.d.f. is $f_3$, then I know that $$f_3(x_3) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^1 2e^{-x_2-2x_3}dx_2dx_3$$ when $x_3>0$ and $0$ otherwise. How do I find the p.d.f. of $X_1+X_2$ though? Do I really need to find it to answer part (b)?

$\color{red}{(c)}$ I'm just writing the expressions for $f_1,f_2,f_3$ since I found this calculation trivial:
$$f_1(x_1) = 1$$ when $0<x_1<1$ and $0$ otherwise.
$$f_2(x_2) = e^{-x_2}$$ when $x_2>0$ and $0$ otherwise.
$$f_3(x_3) = 2e^{-2x_2}$$ when $x_3>0$ and $0$ otherwise. Clearly, $f = f_1f_2f_3$, so this gives concrete proof that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are indeed independent, i.e. solves part (a) too.

$\color{red}{(d)}$ Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, the conditional p.d.f should be the same as the marginal p.d.f. of $X_1$, right? In which case, it'd be $1$ for $0<x_1<1$ and $0$ otherwise. Hope this is correct!

What would happen if $X_1,X_2,X_3$ weren't independent, suppose the distribution was of the form $ae^{-x_2-2x_3-x_2x_3}$ for appropriate choice of $a$. How would I solve part (d) then?

Thanks a lot!

---

**Update 1:** For the p.d.f. of $Y = X_1 + X_2$, first I shall compute the c.d.f. which should be
$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = \int_0^1\int_0^\infty e^{-x_2}\mathbf{1}_{\{x_1+x_2\le y\}} dx_2dx_1$$
We have $0\le x_1\le 1$ and $0\le x_2\le\infty$, we want to integrate over $x_1+x_2\le y$. Clearly we must also have $x_1\le y$ and $x_2\le y$. Would it be correct to rewrite the integral as
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{y-x_1} e^{-x_2} dx_2dx_1 = \int_0^1 1 - e^{x_1-y} dx_1 = 1 - e^{-y}(e-1)$$
If the above is correct, then $$f_Y(y) = \frac{\partial F_Y(y)}{\partial y} = e^{-y}(e-1)$$
Is this fine? I don't know how to solve (b) with this, though.

Comment: $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent because the p.d.f. of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ can be factored. This implies that the vector $(X_1,X_2)$ is independent with $X_3$ and then for every measurable function $f$, $f(X_1,X_2)$ is independent with $X_3$, in particular $f(u,v)=u+v$.

Comment: In general, you can prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables (or random vectors) and $f,g$ are measurable functions, then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Thank you, that is very helpful! However, could you also see my calculation of the p.d.f. of $X_1+ X_2$, and perhaps throw some light on part $(d)$ of the question?

Comment: The pdf of $X_1+X_2$ look right and d) too. For the special case you propose, you can find the pdf of vector $(X_1,X_2)$ and use conditional distribution's formulas

Comment: Cool, thank you! You may want to document this as an answer, especially the part about measurable functions seems like an important result.